# HTTP POST Firebase Cloud Function "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

Tags: node.js, firebase, cors, http-post, google-cloud-functions

I try to make HTTP POST request but I get this error
(everything is ok when I use same function on my angularjs project using `__$http__`) I searched similar questions here but I think I am missing a basic point on my JS request code.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-MYAPP.cloudfunctions.net/app/MYURL' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Firebase side:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.post('/MYURL', (req, res) => {

   // my function goes here
   var clientKey = req.body.clientKey;
   return res.status(200).send(clientKey);

});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My request code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "https://us-central1-MYAPP.cloudfunctions.net/app/MYURL", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhttp.send("clientKey=XXXXX");
```

Comment: Where are you exporting an HTTP function uses your Express app?  The code you're showing now doesn't define any functions that would be serviced by an HTTP request.

Comment: Yes I forgot. added "exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);"

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been a couple of days after my question, I want to share the result here. I contacted to Firebase Support and got replied that everything should be ok with my code. I know it is funny but it works without any CORS error right now. The fact is that I really did not change anything.